# PowerBI Convert in "K" and "M"

Tags: powerbi

I have a table with different data in PowerBI, here an example:

```
Index  KPI 
 1     340980329
 2     230000
```

I have used the PowerBI solution to convert the "KPI" columns approximating the decimals, but it seems that we can choose either "K" or "M", obtaining:

```
Index  KPI 
 1     340.980K
 2     230K
```

but how can I use different decimal approximations according to the amount? for instance:

```
Index  KPI 
 1     340M
 2     230K
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a custom column where you can format the numbers to display as required.

```
=IF('TableName'[KPI]>1000000,
    FORMAT(abc/1000000,"0.00M"),
    FORMAT('TableName'[KPI]/100000,"0.00K")
)
```

Note: The drawback is the data will not be numeric data type, so you cannot use it to do arithmetic operations.

Although, You can use the same logic in a measure to do arithmetic operation and then later convert the output to a string using FORMAT function

You can refer to the following articles to know more details:

- [PowerBIdocs.com](https://powerbidocs.com/2020/09/26/custom-display-units-in-power-bi/#:%7E:text=Now%20create%20a%20custom%20display%20units%20based%20on%20some%20conditions%3A)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67866977/6908282)